# Image overlap the text when I resize the window CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, overlap

I'm working on a personal project and I have a problem with overlapping when I resize the window.
Basically until now my page is divided in 3 sections, header (which is sticky), middle/hero and last section with the products.

The problem is when I make my page less higher, the images with the coffees are overlapping the text.

My code is here:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20em, 1fr));
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  width: calc(100vw - 64px);

  justify-content: center;
}

.text-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  margin: 0 5vw 0 5vw;
  padding: 0 2vw 0 2vw;
}

.text-section h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

/* <p> color */
.ph {
  color: #3c4043;
}

.image-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-image: url(https://www.illy.com/dw/image/v2/BBDD_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_illycaffe/default/dw9a7f00e7/products/Coffee/Coffee-Ground/9893ME_coffee_ground-espresso_can-classico-roast-250gr-zagnoli-decorated_illy-shop/DecoratoOZ_GroundClassico_800x800px.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 15em;
  margin: 2vw;
}

.main-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;

}

.illy,
.lavazza,
.starbucks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 15em;
  height: 25em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/claudiuu/full/ZEWmRzR

[here is the overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBVxk.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your overlap see here with extremely reduced height and width still fine (because of flex display): https://prnt.sc/ulbeuk

Comment: If you stretch more and height and width you will get.
https://imgur.com/afQ20Km

Comment: `..hero` section is causing the overlapping you should make the `hight `dynamic using some JS or jquery.

Comment: @AhmadDalao it can't be done just with css?

Comment: ` height: calc(100vh - 64px);` changing the 100vh with 100% it helps but I will lose the hero view.

Comment: Based on @AhmadDalao replay I played a bit and is working if I change:
`height: calc(100vh - 64px);` with `min-height: calc(100vh - 64px);`

Comment: @claudiu you can still fix it using fixed values but I highly recommend using Js to add the hight in a dynamic way. since you can't open all the devices and fix the hight and make it fit for it. Also, there should be other roundabouts it.